# How to modify array values?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I am having some issues converting my Linux skills to python. Any pointers in the correct direction would be much appreciated.

**Overview**

I have 2 lists that are dynamically created; the number of items in the list can change depending on lots of different factors.
For the sake of this example, I have created 2 static lists to represent the data pulled from somewhere else (file_root and docs_directory):

```
def find_directory_function():
        global full_path
        file_root = ['/home/work'] #number of values here can change!
        # number of values below can change!
        docs_directory = ['important.docs/','random.directory/', dev.stuff/]
        PATH = []
        full_path=[]

        for i in docs_directory:
                PATH = file_root.join(i)
                full_path.append(PATH)
                print full_path

find_directory_function()
```

**Expectations**

I want the output to be another array (full_path) with the following values:

```
full_path = ["/home/work/important.docs/",
             "/home/work/random.directory/",
             "/home/work/dev.stuff/",]
```

**Issues**

1. The following exception is being raised:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
       find_directory_function()
     File "test.py", line 11, in find_directory_function
       PATH = file_root.join(i)
   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'
   ```
2. Even if I managed to manipulate the strings and place them in an array, they will still be missing a "/" (slash) in the middle of the joined values.

Comment: if `file_root` is a list, how to join the files with the directories? with a combination? a product?

Comment: try `os.path.join(root, i)`, also file_root should be a string, not a list of strings

Comment: I'm assuming from your comment that the number of file_root directories can change. Is that correct? If so, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os.path.join`:

```
import os
import copy
def find_directory_function():
    global full_path
    file_root = ['/home/work'] #number of values here can change!
    docs_directory = ['important.docs/','random.directory/', dev.stuff/] #number of values here can change!
    PATH = []
    full_path=[]

    for i in docs_directory:
        # since file_root can be an array, use copy to grab a copy 
        # of the array
        args = copy.copy(file_root)
        # and stick `i` on the end of that array so
        # that we have our full param list for os.path.join
        args.append(i)
        PATH = os.path.join(*args)
        full_path.append(PATH)
        print full_path

find_directory_function()
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you. I cannot up vote yet but this is exactly what i need!

Answer (score 0):

Change `file_root = ['/home/work']` to `file_root = '/home/work/'`

or do the following changes in the `for` loop:

```
file_root[0] + "/" + i
```

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
import os.path
# ...

def make_full_paths(roots, paths):
    "roots is a list of prefixes. paths is a list of suffixes."
    full_paths = []
    for root in roots:
        for path in paths:
            full_paths.append(os.path.join(root, path))
    return full_paths
```

There are other ways you could do it too...as a generator function with `yield` (probably not what you want, since you may want to use the full_paths more than once); or with https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product , which would make it a one-liner (more advanced):

```
import itertools
import os.path
# ...

def make_full_paths2(roots, paths):
    "roots is a list of prefixes. paths is a list of suffixes."
    return [os.path.join(root, path) for root, path in itertools.product(roots, paths)]
```